# Arrays: Left Rotation | Cracking the coding interview Hacker Rank - (Terminated due to time out)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am a pretty average programmer and am attempting to better my skills through different challenges provided by the Hacker-rank website. I was attempting to solve this Array left rotation algorithm and was able to pass every test case except the last one which is a large file of numbers. After doing some research I have found that the Terminated due to timeout error is due to the algorithm not being efficient enough, I suppose hacker rank has some kind of time limit or speed test for each test case and my algorithm was not fast enough. Below I have provided the question asked and the code I implemented if anyone can help me reduce optimize this algorithm (EXPLAIN!) why my algorithm is slower I would really appreciate it. MUCH LOVE CK

EXPLANATION: 
A left rotation operation on an array of size n shifts each of the array's elements 1 unit to the left. For example, if 2 left rotations are performed on array [1,2,3,4,5], then the array would become [3,4,5,1,2].

Given an array of n integers and a number,d, perform d left rotations on the array. Then print the updated array as a single line of space-separated integers.

Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of n (the number of integers) and d (the number of left rotations you must perform). 
The second line contains n space-separated integers describing the respective elements of the array's initial state.

Constraints

1 <= n <= 10^5 
1 <= d <= n 
1 <= ai <= 10^6

Output Format 
Print a single line of n space-separated integers denoting the final state of the array after performing d left rotations.

Sample Input

```
5 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Sample Output

```
5 1 2 3 4
```

When we perform d=4 left rotations, the array undergoes the following sequence of changes: 
[1,2,3,4,5] --> [2,3,4,5,1] --> [3,4,5,1,2] --> [4,5,1,2,3] --> [5,1,2,3,4]

Thus, we print the array's final state as a single line of space-separated values, which is 5 1 2 3 4.

Code:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

vector<int> array_left_rotation(vector<int> a, int n, int k) {
    int tmp=0,x=0;
    while(x < k){
        tmp = a[0];
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            if(i+1 == n) a[i]= tmp;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return a;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    int k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for(int a_i = 0;a_i < n;a_i++){
        cin >> a[a_i];
    }
    vector<int> output = array_left_rotation(a, n, k);
    for(int i = 0; i < n;i++)
        cout << output[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::rotate`?

Comment: OH my gosh @PaulMcKenzie I had no idea there was such a thing! thanks so much

Comment: I might miss something obvious, but why implement a rotate function at all? You can just read the input and pass it straight to the output. You should only skip the first `n-d` numbers which you store in an array and print in the end?

Comment: Two possible improvements are reducing time complexity from O(kn) to O(n) (there is an answer below which shows how) and avoiding copying std::vector into the function - use call by reference.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my more efficient algorithm -

### Reversal Algorithm

To rotate an array at position `k` (moving `k` to `n` elements to left), we can do this:

1. Reverse subarray `arr[0 .... k - 1]` which is `O(k)`
2. Reverse subarray `arr[k .... n - 1]` which is `O(n - k)`
3. Lastly, Reverse subarray `arr[0 .... n]` which is `O(n)`

The overall complexity is `O(n)` and space complexity is constant.

You have to take care corner cases like `k >= n`, `k < 0` etc.

```
void leftRotate(vector<int>& arr, int k)
{
    int n = (int)arr.size();
    if(k >= n) k = k % n;
    reverse(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + k);
    reverse(arr.begin() + k, arr.end());
    reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end());
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

To me the task sounds like there's no need to perform the rotation at all. You just need to **print** out the result, skipping the rotation altogether!

Basically all you need is to perform the following:

1. read `n` and `d`
2. create a vector and read-in first `d` numbers into it
3. read-in the rest of the numbers and immediately output them
4. output the numbers in the vector

That is all and I don't think you can get more efficient than completely omitting the work ;-)